# Opencart 2.x checkout / Success add tracking code for specific product

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I am looking to add a block of JavaScript to the success.tpl file only if a specific product is purchased.

I know I have to edit the following file to place the id check.

```
template/common/success.tpl
```

I just need help figuring out how to edit the controller to create or allow the use of the variables needed.

```
catalog/controller/checkout/success.php
```

Everyone is talking about getting the order ID but I cant find anything that talks about receiving a list of the products purchased.  Does anyone know how I can manage to get the product IDs so that I can create the check against them.

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Tested on Opencart 2.2.0.0 :

open:

```
catalog/controller/checkout/success.php
```

Find:

```
if (isset($this->session->data['order_id'])) {
```

Add after it:

```
$order_product_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_product WHERE order_id = '" . (int)$this->session->data['order_id'] . "'");
$order_products_id = array();
foreach ($order_product_query->rows as $product){
    $order_products_id[] = $product['product_id'];
}
$data['order_products_id'] = $order_products_id;
```

Then open `tpl` file:

```
catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/success.tpl
```

And add this:

```
<?php if(isset($order_products_id)){
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($order_products_id);
    echo '</pre>';
    $specific_product_id = 28;
    if(in_array($specific_product_id, $order_products_id)){ ?>
        <script>alert('Yes, it is');</script>
    <?php }
} ?>
```

Hope this help you.